# How would I know if I am wearing all-heavy armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Heavy Armor skill perks *Well Fitted*, *Tower of Strength*, *Matching Set* and *Reflect Blows* rely on the prerequisite that the character must have equipped all-heavy armor.

How do I know a body armor part is heavy armor? Are they identified as such or does it depend on the material used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The description will tell you if the item is heavy or light armour. Refer to the image below. (The small, dark grey text just above and to the left of the item name)

[image]

Comment: Nice spoiler image.

Comment: What is he spoiling? it's immediately viewable in the smithing tree what armors you can make.

Comment: That's a nice looking helmet!

Comment: I edited the image. Sorry I didn't really consider it a spoiler, but I guess it could be seen as one.

Comment: @normanthesquid The spoiler is the blurry word left of the word helmet.

Answer (score 4):

It depends entirely on the materials used.

These are all the materials that are considered [heavy](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_Armor_(Skyrim)):

- Iron
- Imperial
- Steel
- Steel Plate
- Falmer
- Ancient Nord
- Dwarven
- Orcish
- Ebony
- Daedric
- Dragonplate

Conversely, here are all the [light armor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Armor_(Skyrim)) types:

- Hide Armor
- Imperial Light Armor
- Studded Armor
- Leather Armor
- Thieves Guild Armor
- Dark Brotherhood Armor
- Nightingale Armor
- Elven Armor
- Scaled Armor
- Glass Armor
- Forsworn Armor
- Stormcloak Armor (Officer Armor as well)
- Dragon Armor (Dragonscale version only)

You can also check by examining the armor from your inventory.  It'll say heavy or light.