# How is armor in skyrim classified?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to make a warrior build for my character in skyrim, and I want light armor for my character because I have a shield and heavy armor will just weigh my down... What armor is light armor though? Is there certain pieces of iron armor that counts as light?

Comment: if you will be high level at heavy armor you will get an perk that makes heavy armor weight 0

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37003/how-would-i-know-if-i-am-wearing-all-heavy-armor

Comment: Both light armor and heavy armor can provide maximum protection (at AR 567) with smithing, both can be made to weigh 0 while equipped, but light armor has less frivolous perks, meaning more perks in more useful skill trees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Iron armor is heavy armor.  Light armor categories are Hide, Leather, Studded, Elven, Scaled, Glass, and Dragon Scale.

[Light armor info](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Armor_%28Skyrim%29), [Heavy armor info](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_Armor_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: It's also worth noting that an armor's type is noted on its detail screen in the inventory.

Comment: @Iszi, yeah good point, the answer of the question in yx's comment shows that.